# java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error when run quickfix.examples.executor.main in idea

Tags: quickfix

I download the quickfixj v2.3.1 from https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj, and then run the below command:

- mvn clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin
- mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin

Then open the project in idea. When I execute "quickfix.examples.executor.main" in idea, the error cured.

[image]

I think the reason is not about my idea memory config.
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m

I am very confused. Anyone could help resolve the problem?